# show: $\langle a,b | a^2=b^2\rangle \cong\langle a,b |ab=b^{-1}a \rangle$ and find direct isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-topology

I used Van-Kampen theorem to show that $\pi_1(K^2) = \langle a,b : ab=b^{-1}a\rangle$ then I used Van-Kampen again to split $K^2$ to two Mebius strips and when taking the amalgamation with the intersection of the Mebius strips I got the free group $\langle a,b | a^2=b^2\rangle$.

I am trying to find the direct isomorphism - for $a$ I got:

$ab=b^{-1}a \Rightarrow a=b^{-1}ab^{-1} \Rightarrow a^2=a(b^{-1}ab^{-1}) = (ab^{-1})^2$ so I can define the isomorphism on $a \rightarrow(ab^{-1})$.

But I don't succeed to find an expression the $b^2$, I was trying to search in the polygonal representation of $K^2$ but could't make it.
I would really appreciate an answer which gives a motivation/intuition for $b^2$ expression from $K^2$ characteristics.

Comment: You seem to be mixing the $a,b$ from one of the two groups with $a,b$ the other. I would use $c,d$ for one of the groups to avoid this.

Comment: We can map $a\mapsto a$ and $b\mapsto ab^{-1}$.

Comment: You can also do $ab=b^{-1}a$: $b(ab)a=b(b^{-1}a)a$: $(ba)^2=a^2$

Comment: @Berci may you please give some more details, I don't clearly see how does it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $ab=b^{-1}a$ implies $bab=a$ and so suggests $(ab)^2=abab=a^2$ as something to build the isomorphism on.
Indeed, we check that 
$$\begin{align}\phi\colon \langle \,a,b\mid a^2=b^2\,\rangle&\to  \langle \,a,b\mid ab=b^{-1}a\,\}\\
a&\mapsto a\\b&\mapsto ab\end{align}$$
and
$$\begin{align}\psi\colon \langle \,a,b\mid ab=b^{-1}a\,\rangle&\to  \langle \,a,b\mid a^2=b^2\,\}\\
a&\mapsto a\\b&\mapsto a^{-1}b\end{align}$$
are well-defined because 
$$\phi(a^2)=a^2=abab=\phi(b)^2=\phi(b^2)$$
and
$$\psi(ab)=a a^{-1}b=b =b^{-1}b^2=b^{-1}a^2
=b^{-1}a\cdot a=\psi(b)^{-1}\psi(a)=\psi(b^{-1}a) $$
and are inverse of each other because 
$$\psi(\phi(a))=\psi(a)=a,\qquad \psi(\phi(b))=\psi(ab)=aa^{-1}b=b$$
and
$$\phi(\psi(a)=\phi(a)=a\qquad \phi(\psi(b))=\phi(a^{-1}b)=a^{-1}ab=b. $$
We conclude that $\phi$ is an isomorphism (with inverse $\psi$).